# How do you group by years from 'created_at', using ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, mysql2

In SQL, I'd use something like this:

```
SELECT year(created_at)
FROM videos
GROUP BY year(created_at)
```

How can I run this query with Rails?

I've tried this:

```
Video.all.group_by { |m| m.created_at.year }
```

... but this will return ALL my records grouped by the corresponding years, which is not entirely bad, except it's returning hundreds of records, when I only need to know the years.

Any pointers?

In case you're wondering I'm using Rails 5.1.5 and MariaDB (10.2.14-MariaDB-10.2.14+maria~xenial-log).

Comment: you mean you want only years? `Event.all.group_by { |m| m.created_at.year }.keys`

Comment: Well, I feel dumb now. That works. Would that query be just as efficient as the SQL I posted?

Comment: @user3209270: sadly no, that's one of the slowest and most wasteful ways to do the thing.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this to get an array of unique years...

```
Video.pluck(:created_at).map{ |dt| dt.year }.uniq
```

Answer (score 3):

Turns out, `pluck` accepts expressions, not only column names. So you can do this for max efficiency (at the cost of portability).

```
Video.distinct.pluck("year(created_at)") # mysql
Video.distinct.pluck("extract(year from created_at)") # postgresql
```

Same efficiency as running raw sql (from my other answer), but looks a bit more ActiveRecord-y.

If you want a portable solution, then I can't think of anything better than [Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51554929/125816).

Answer (score 1):

Not everything can be expressed in activerecord-speak without losing efficiency here or there. Or some things can't be expressed at all. That's why you can run arbitrary SQL:

```
Video.connection.execute("select year(created_at)....")
```

Having actually read your SQL, you want distinct years of the records? So, perhaps this? Should be even faster (*benchmarking needed*).

```
SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(created_at)  FROM videos
```

Comment: Definitely, however the paranoid in me was urging me to find a solution in ActiveRecord, in case the DBMS couldn't handle the SQL for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only years from data you can do

```
videos = Video.group("created_at").select("videos.created_at")
```

it will fetch only `created_at` column

and you can access year from created_at column by

```
videos.first.created_at.year
```

Comment: Better than loading full videos, but still this code will be instantiating some video models, which is a total waste of cpu cycles.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
Video.all.map {|u| u.created_at.year}
```

This would return a array containing the years in which each `Video` was created.

Comment: That will load all videos, in their entirety.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using

```
Event.group("strftime('%Y', created_at)")
```

For example:

```
Event.group("strftime('%Y', created_at)").count
```

has the output:

```
{"2019"=>456}
```

You can even group by a child's `created_at` this way:

```
Application.group("strftime('%Y', events.created_at)")
```

This would require, that an `applications` has many `events` in my particular case.